# how to use a setter instead of New JWTAuthenticationFilter in SecurityConfig.java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I'm working with spring-boot (using JWT and spring security ) and i have a  class configSecurity  in spring-boot with this code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/ListProjects/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll(); //allow CORS option calls
       http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
 http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAutorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

And a class : JWTAuthenticationFilter.java which containts the contsructor :

```
 @Autowired
 public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
  {
      this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }
```

My goal is to  change the line in securityConfig:

```
  http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
```

into somthing like this :

```
http.addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter.SetJWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
```

So i have added the Annocation @Autoweird in class SecurityConfig as This :

```
@Autowired
private JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
```

So i didn't know how to make this method in  JWTAuthenticationFilter.java , 
i did somthing like this :

```
          @Autowired
          public JWTAuthenticationFilter SetJWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
          this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
          return  // (1)
       }
```

**(1)**  : So what should i return in this case? i don't want to use somthing like new JWTAuthenticationFilter () .. , Any idea ? or i'm not doing this in the right way .. ?

**EDIT**

**after adding these changes , i'm not able to authenticate users , so not able to get the token of each user , i think the problem goes with the new class i have added it implements a method that returns null**

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

@Configuration
public class CustomAuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Any idea ??

Comment: What did you do in the old method `authenticationManager()` in `SecurityConfig`? You need to implement similar logic in `authenticate(...)` method there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part of code

```
 @Autowired
 public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
      this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }
```

means that if you create `JWTAuthenticationFilter` as a Spring component(not via calling `new`) `AuthenticationManager` will be automatically autowired into that class and you do not need to run any kind of setters.

What your `authenticationManager()` method is doing? If you just create a new `@Bean` of `AuthenticationManager` you may just do it in a separate class and It will be automatically autowired to  `JWTAuthenticationFilter`.

Possible solution:
1. Create class:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {
...
}
```

2. Add to `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Autowired
private JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
```

and use `http.addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter);`
3. Stay `JWTAuthenticationFilter` as is.